# Return function value instead of string

Tags: python, python-3.x

It's weird, but it never happened to me before, so I do not know where I'm wrong.
I have this script:

```
import PyEngine

PyEngine.init()

print(PyEngine.info.pack)
```

The `__init__` of PyEngine is this at the moment:

```
import subprocess, sys
class init():
    def __init__(self):
        __checkp__ = subprocess.check_output([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "freeze"])
        self.__packages__ = [r.decode().split("==")[0] for r in __checkp__.split()]
        self.__pack__ = " ".join(self.__packages__)

        print(self.__pack__)

        self.__info__ = info(self)

class info():
    def __init__(self, main):
        self.__pye__ = main

    def pack(self):
        return self.__pye__.__pack__
```

With `print(self.__pack__)`, I get this:

```
Django Jinja2 MarkupSafe PyOpenGL PyTMX PyYAML Pygments Vector2D WMI attrs euclid future glsvg inputs keyboard pbr pyPEG2 pygame pyglet pygobject pyperclip pytz qutebrowser six stevedore tmx virtualenv virtualenv-clone virtualenvwrapper wheel
```

But with `print(PyEngine.info.pack)`, I get this:

```
<function info.pack at 0x0000000003072A60>
```

I can not understand...

Also, I would like to know how I could, if I wanted to, use the super class. Despite having tried so many times on this subject, honestly even now I can not fully understand how it works.

Comment: Yes, `PyEngine.info.pack` (__not__ `PyEngine.info.pack()`!) is a function object. What's the problem here?

Comment: The problem was that I thought that by doing print(PyEngine.info.pack) it would return me self .__ pye __.__ pack__ So what is the mistake?

Comment: `PyEngine.info.pack` does not _call_ the function. In Python, everything is a function, so, for example, `str.format, set.__init__, len` is valid Python.

Comment: So how should I do?

Comment: What `self` would you expect it to use? `PyEngine` is a module. `PyEngine.info` is a class. `PyEngine.info.pack` is an unbound method of that class. You haven't even created a `PyEngine.info` instance anywhere.

Comment: You should call it, obviously. Just like any regular function, like `print`. But then you'll face another error that'll complain about an invalid number of arguments supplied to it.

Comment: Also, what super class are you referring to? You have two classes, but both of them just inherit from the default `object`. Did you want to call one of the builtin methods on `object`?

Comment: In what sense is not associated with that class? pack() is not a function of the info class?

Comment: As for the super class, from what I understand, the child class can inherit variable or function from the parent class, or did I misunderstand? In the __init__ file of the module, all classes that will be created in the future should be children of the init class. Not having understood the topic well, however, I would not embark on something without having understood more ...